# Why does spi2 point to a different address as spi when using copy constructor

Tags: c++

i need to get a byte-representation of an integer, so im trying to create a `char*` from a standard `int`. Why does spi2 point to a different address as spi when using copy constructor.

```
   int main(int argc, char* argv) {
        std::cout << "[dbg0]" << std::endl;
        int foo = 2100000000;
        std::cout << "&foo: " << &foo << " - val: " << foo << " - sizeof: " << sizeof(foo) << std::endl;
        std::shared_ptr<int> spi = std::make_shared<int>(foo);
        std::cout << "&spi: " << &spi << " - val: " << *spi << std::endl;
        std::shared_ptr<int> spi2(spi);
        std::cout << "&spi2: " << &spi2 << " - val: " << *spi2 << std::endl;
        int* bar = &foo;
        std::cout << "&bar: " << &bar << " - val: " <<*bar << std::endl;
        bar -= 8;
        std::cout << "&bar-8: " << &bar << " - val: " <<*bar << std::endl;
        char* bytewiseint = (char*)&bar;
        std::cout << "&bytewiseint: " << &bytewiseint << " - val: " <<*bytewiseint << std::endl;
        char* bytewiseint2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&foo);
        std::cout << "&bytewiseint2: " << &bytewiseint2 << " - val: " <<*bytewiseint2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[dbg1]" << std::endl;
        for(unsigned int c = 0; *(bytewiseint+c) != '\0'; c++) {
            std::cout << "c=" << c << ". " << *(bytewiseint+c) << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "[dbg2]" << std::endl;
        std::getchar();
        return 0;
```

Comment: Now compare the `int*` pointers `&*spi` and `&*spi2`.

Comment: because `spi` and `spi2` are two different variables, so have different address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have:

```
int foo = etc...;
```

The address of this int is &foo.

When you use make_shared using foo, a new foo is created by make_shared and you get a shared_ptr object returned. This object contains the address of the foo created by make_shared and not the foo you created.

I see where you:

```
bar -= 8;
```

and then you:

```
cout << &bar ...
```

This is the address of bar and not the address inside bar. The address of bar does not change when you change the contents of bar. The contents of bar is *bar. If you cout that you will see the address contained in bar.

This is why &sp1 and &sp2 are different. They are different objects. You need to look inside these object to see the pointer they own.